# Editor Headers Merging to One Line

Tags: interface

I noticed something very annoying , usually at the top of the viewport there will be 2 lines with options (Image 1). but when I'm using 2.9(the latest version I can use renderman), the lines are merged into one(Image 2)(notice the options dropdown between the IPR button and the render mode). the issue becomes even more apparent when I'm using the texture painting tab (Image 3). can anyone please explain me what's happening because I don't know how to begin fixing this
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I have no RenderMan so I have no idea if it has anything to do with this, but I cannot reproduce your issue. When I open Blender 2.90.0 I have two lines of menu just like in 3.4.1. If I right-click on the menu bar and disable _Show Tool Settings_, the second line disappears - but then the _Options_ dropdown is gone as well. Disabling _Show Tool Settings_ I can do in the latest version of Blender as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Preferences > Interface* and check/uncheck *Region Overlap*:

[image: OLap]

Comment: ...but that doesn't remove the "second line" of the header as requested.